# How to make a scatterplot with positive and negative x-axis in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a scatterplot that displays the positive y-axis and the negative and positive x-axes. Points will be either open or filled based on which month the data is from, and will have a different shape for each individual we collected data from. The origin will represent time 0 (when an event happened), and the negative x-axis will represent time before the event, positive x-axis is the time after the event. I also want to look at the difference in the mean slope of the points between before and after the event. I've included a photo of what I'm aiming for (this image doesn't include the different shapes for different individuals, just a rough sketch of what I'm looking to make). If you need any more information on my data, happy to provide that.

I have not tried to experiment with this yet, since I'm very new to using R and haven't been successful finding other's code for a similar plot.

Comment: You can manipulate the span of x and y axes by passing the `xlim` and `ylim` parameters to the `plot()` function in base R.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for instructions on how to create a question that people will be able and inclined to answer. Images of data and high-level descriptions of what you want  to accomplish will garner more criticism than actual responses.